# how to pass 3 parameters in custom callback() - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, callback

**Config/login_rules.php**

Here for the callback function **check_email_existence**

I want to pass three parameters which are **(email,table, field)**

```
<?php


/**
* SETTING VALIDATION RULES FOR THE LOGIN FORM
*/

$config['login_settings'] = array(

        array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|xss_clean',
                'errors' => array(
                        'required' => 'You must provide a %s.',
                ),
        ),

        array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean|check_email_existence'
        )
);
?>
```

I have extended the form validation helper **libraries/MY_Form_validation.php**

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

        protected $CI;

        public function __construct($config = array())
        {
                parent::__construct($config);

                $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }



        function check_email_existence($email,$table,$field) {   

            $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('check_email_existence', 'This %s id is not registered.');
            $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table WHERE $field = '".$email."' ");
            $row = $query->row();
            return ($row->count > 0) ? 'success' : 'failure';

        }


 }//class

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A callback function accepts two parameters: ($postdata, $param).

$param receives whatever you define as the rule's parameter via [...] after the rule's name:

```
'rules' => 'required|trim|valid_email|xss_clean|check_email_existence[table,field]'

function check_email_existence($email, $param) {
  // extract table and field from $param
...
```